# Conditional Includes

Tags: c#, .net

I would like to know how I can change this query:

```
events = _database.Events
         .Include("Contacts")
         .ToList();
```

To include only contacts having their property "Type" set to "event".

I'm using EntityFramework, _database is its context.

Comment: Where is the lambda expression you're asking about?

Comment: Too ambiguous - what type of object is _database? What are the details of the Contact class?

Comment: I'm sorry I seem to have mixed up the names. I always thought this was called a lambda expression. What's the correct name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, it's worth understanding that the code you posted doesn't include a [lambda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) at all. "Query not in query expression syntax" isn't the same as "lambda expression".

I suspect it would be a bad idea to return event objects with a partially-filled entity reference set. However, you could do this:

```
_database.Events
         .Select(e => new { Event = e,
                            EventContacts e.Contacts
                                           .Where(c => c.Type == "event") });
```